# Error with git and heroku

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-cli

Trying to put the application on the server `heroku', but it does not work, do everything as instructed
 Install the Heroku CLI
Download and install the Heroku CLI.

If you haven't already, log in to your Heroku account and follow the prompts to create a new SSH public key.

```
$ heroku login
```

Create a new Git repository
Initialize a git repository in a new or existing directory

```
$ cd my-project/
$ git init
$ heroku git:remote -a name
```

Deploy your application
Commit your code to the repository and deploy it to Heroku using Git.

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -am "make it better"
$ git push heroku master
```

Existing Git repository
For existing repositories, simply add the heroku remote

```
$ heroku git:remote -a name
```

After entering the command

```
$ git push heroku master
```

The error comes out

```
 c:\Games\discord>git push heroku master    Counting objects: 323, done.
    Compressing objects: 100% (312/312), done.
    Writing objects: 100% (323/323), 360.29 KiB | 922.00 KiB/s, done.
    Total 323 (delta 31), reused 0 (delta 0)
    remote: Compressing source files... done.
    remote: Building source:
    remote:
    remote:  !     No default language could be detected for this app.
    remote:                         HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect 
    the
    buildpack to use for this application automatically.
    remote:                         See 
    https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildp
    acks
    remote:
    remote:  !     Push failed
    remote: Verifying deploy...
    remote:
    remote: !       Push rejected to name.
    remote:
    To https://git.heroku.com/name.git
    ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
    error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/name.git'
```

This is underlined in red

```
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)

error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/name.git'
```

Tried to write "pull" before "push" but it didn't help

I have windows 7

Comment: What kind of development language (php/node.js/others) you are using for your application ?

Comment: Check in github that the repository exists and in the local repository that the project has either been cloned or is updated with the remote

Comment: Ashok JayaPrakash, I use node.js

Answer (score 0):

Cool Let me explain this.
This worked for me.
First of all
I expect you have already install heroku cli
If not visit this : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-command-line
If you can't install it.
let me know
Update or set you public ssh key

```
$ heroku login
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa`
$ heroku keys:add
$ heroku keys:remove yourlocalworkstation
$ heroku keys
$ ssh -v git@heroku.com
```

you can check here
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys

Now, undo all the inits that you have made

```
$ rmdir .git
$ rmdir /s .git
```

If you see red error like paragraphs in your command line
don't worry and follow the steps down.

After this follow this final steps

```
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Initial Commit"
$ heroku create yourappname
$ git remote -v
$ git push heroku master
```

Now, it's done.